# Displaying categories/subcategories in sencha

Tags: extjs

I have recently develop a sencha app about  displaying categories/sub categories. It displayed the main categories, but does not display the sub categories on clicking any category.

My store is--

```
Ext.define('listdemo.store.Sections', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

config : {
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'listdemo.model.Sections',

    proxy:{
        type   : 'ajax',
        url:'http://localhost/catt.php',

        reader:{
                    type:'json',
                    rootProperty:'categories'       
                }

    }
}
});
```

Model code is------

```
Ext.define('listdemo.model.Sections', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    fields: ['categories_id', 'categories_name','subcategories'],


}
});
```

And the view is----

```
Ext.define('listdemo.view.Main',{
       extend: 'Ext.NestedList',
       xtype:'main',
       requires: [
            'Ext.TitleBar',
            'Ext.dataview.List',
            'Ext.data.Store',
            'Ext.dataview.NestedList'
        ],

       config:{
           title: 'Categories',
           //store:'Sections',
           items:[
           {
               xtype:'list',
               itemTpl:'{categories_name}',
               title:'Categories',
               store:'Sections',

            }
        ]
    }
});
```

My php file returns----

> {"categories":[{"categories_id":"1","categories_name":"Hardware","subcategories":[{"categories_id":"4","categories_name":"Graphics
>   Cards"},{"categories_id":"5","categories_name":"Printers"},{"categories_id":"6","categories_name":"Monitors"},{"categories_id":"7","categories_name":"Speakers"},{"categories_id":"8","categories_name":"Keyboards"},{"categories_id":"9","categories_name":"Mice"},{"categories_id":"16","categories_name":"Memory"},{"categories_id":"17","categories_name":"CDROM
>   Drives"}]},{"categories_id":"2","categories_name":"Software","subcategories":[{"categories_id":"18","categories_name":"Simulation"},{"categories_id":"19","categories_name":"Action"},{"categories_id":"20","categories_name":"Strategy"}]},{"categories_id":"3","categories_name":"DVD
>   Movies","subcategories":[{"categories_id":"10","categories_name":"Action"},{"categories_id":"11","categories_name":"Science
>   Fiction"},{"categories_id":"12","categories_name":"Comedy"},{"categories_id":"13","categories_name":"Cartoons"},{"categories_id":"14","categories_name":"Thriller"},{"categories_id":"15","categories_name":"Drama"}]}]}

What will I do to display the sub categories  under main categories.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your model definition to include field types, and register a custom data type to use for subcategories.

Start by including this before the models load:

```
Ext.data.Types.ARRAY = {
    type: 'Array'
};
```

Next update your model to look like this:

```
Ext.define('listdemo.model.Sections', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [{
            name: 'categories_id',
            type: 'int'
        },{ 
            name: 'categories_name',
            type: 'string'
        },{
            name: 'subcategories'
            type: Ext.data.Types.ARRAY
        }]
    }
});
```

Now once your store loads, check the records manually via the web console to ensure the array of subcategories is saved. You will need to add a listener for itemtap on the list, and then grab the subcategories and either:

-Reload the original store manually with the subcategories array. This should refresh the list, but you will lose the original store and there won't be any card animation.

-Set up a second list/store that will be reloaded manually with the subcategories, which will allow for the change card animation and maintain the original store for back navigation.

Answer (score 0):

1. give your store the Store Id

2.pass the parameter categories_name and select the subcategory whose parent directory is categories_name 
success: function (response)
    {

searchresponse2 = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);// getting response from server

//searchresponse2 is array storing 1st result in array index[0]

searchresponse2=searchresponse2[0];

var categoriesid=searchresponse2.categories;//getting 1st 
values"categories_id":"1","categories_name":"Hardware"

```
         var categoriesname=searchresponse2.categories_name;

                del_categoriesid=[];//declaring array
                del_categoriesname=[];

           for(var i= 0;i<searchresponse2.length;i++)
                {
                    del_categoriesid[i]=searchresponse2[i].categories;
                    del_categoriesname[i]=searchresponse2[i].categories_name;
                }// looping through all values


                for(var j= 0;j < searchresponse2.length;j++)
                {
```

Ext.getStore('storeid').add({categories:del_categoriesid[j], categories_name:del_categoriesname[j]});
                    }// adding the values of the result in store